# Cassandra: "contains key" operation?

Tags: cassandra

there's some Cassandra operation to verify if a Column Family contains a key? We don't need any row data, only key existence or not.

Best Regards

Comment: You're looking for a column with a specific key value or just any column?

Comment: Before save User data, we want to check if this User exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java then create a SliceQuery for the rowKey and set begin/end values equal to the specific column key you're looking for.  If there is a column with the specific key then the following expression will be true:

```
sliceQuery.execute().get().getColumns().size() > 0
```

Comment: Considering Theo advice, it may be, expensive. What we are looking for is some operation closer to O(1) cost, like yawning lookup. I'll edit my post to be more clear.

Comment: The columns for a row are stored together in sorted order, making for very fast retrieval of slices.  I think this is a fairly fast operation.  Just how many columns are there in a row on average?

Comment: We will try some tests and evaluate this solution. Maybe, a auxiliary columnfamily help to improve this lookup, besides it may cause some inconsistency.

Comment: You can make it O(1) by limiting to 1 column to return. In Hector, you do this by setting the count argument in SliceQuery.setRange.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way of doing it is to ask for the column count for the row, if it's positive the row exists. Because of tombstones there's a gray area around "does not exist". You can remove all columns for a row, but asking for data for the row may result in an empty set of columns instead of `null` (this depends a lot on which driver you're using). You should consider rows that don't have columns as non-existent, and therefore asking for the column count is probably the best way to determine if a row exists or not.

There's some more information about this in the [Cassandra FAQ under "range ghosts"](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts).

Comment: Bear in mind that 'count' will read in all the columns. So if you have a very large row this could take a long time when all you want to know is if it encountered any live columns.

Comment: Yes, this is not advisable for wide row column families.